# "ditry" flag in jsgrid?

Tags: javascript, html, jsgrid

I am trying to find a way such that validation event is triggered only if a row has been modified/updated in jsgrid as opposed to the event triggered every time the row is clicked and left.

Steps

1. Click on a row in the grid to edit.
2. Click on another row without editing any cells on the previous row.

Current Behavior: Validation event is triggered (Alert message is displayed)
Required Behavior: Validation event to be triggered only if a cell value is modified in the grid.

Does jsgrid have any "dirty" field/flag to indicate if a clicked row has been edited?